# follow path not working correct way

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, path

I have a mesh and a curve and trying to make follow path. I have selected the mesh and then curve and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and selected follow path. But the mesh is not moving in the curve shape. Its bouncing here and there. Any suggestion or help why its not in the path.

[image]

[image]

Not rotating in path.

[image]

Comment: I guess your problem is a problem of Origin: You should put the Origin of the Bezier curve at the same point as where your put your ball and where it will begin its loop. So select this point on your Bezier curve then shift S > Cursor to Selected, then ctrl alt shift C > Origin to 3D Cursor.

Comment: @moonboots i tried your method its not working. Is it working for you if so plz provide the answer. Thanks

Comment: Please show you sphere object info and your path constraint for clarity in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sphere object should have

location (0,0,0)

in the object panel.
The origin of the sphere should be in the center of its mesh.

You should have no other keyframed movement.  Keep this initial effort simple.
When you disable the constraint and move through timeline your sphere should have zero movement.

Consider deleting the sphere and creating a new one with the

Follow Path constraint with the 2 [offset] keyframes

in constraint.  This should only take 88 seconds.  Perhaps you need a fresh start.

Comment: The file is attach plz download and check

Comment: There is a suggestion above to show your work.

Comment: Thanks it working for follow path but im sorry i have to ask question for dupliframe i forgot.